# Update rows where a combination of multiple attributes is IN the table

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, where-clause, where-in

I want to update the fields of a table WHERE the combination of three other attributes is IN another table.  I am having some difficulties with the syntax, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Let us know what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

You would normally use `EXISTS` for this:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM b
    WHERE a.col1 = b.col1 AND a.col2 = b.col2 AND a.col3 = b.col3
)
```

Convert the above to an `UPDATE` query.